# Doctrine: Column name `id` referenced for relation from XXX towards YYY does not exist

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, annotations, symfony-3.4

I'm in the midst of creating a Symfony 3.4 e-commerce site.  I've extended the `FOSUserBundle` `User` entity to link to a list of items that have been marked as 'Favorite' by the end user:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AbstractProduct")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_favorites",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *     )
 */
private $favorites;
```

When I attempt to do anything through the console regarding the database, I get the following error:

> Column name `id` referenced for relation from AppBundle\Entity\User towards AppBundle\Entity\AbstractProduct does not exist.

Looking at the [Doctrine annotation documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-joincolumn), whatever's listed as a `JoinColumn` has a `nullable` default of `true`, so I'm at a bit of a loss as to why the system is complaining about a non-existent `User` id.

I *have* looked at [Symfony documentation regarding correctly mapping to abstract classes](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html), but my `AbstractProduct` class has *two* children - `Product` and `FabricProduct`.  I'm not sure how to map those using the technique in the documentation, if it's indeed the way I should go.

Comment: it looks like your product table uses product_id identifier instead of id, try referencedColumnName="product_id"

Comment: This many-to-many annotation is supposed to create a pivot table named `users_favorites` with two columns - `user_id` and `product_id`, with the values being populated by their respective (referenced) `id` columns.  So, that attribute is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot map to abstract classes, because Doctrine is not able to resolve them when creating your model. However, there is a special feature where you can declare an interface and configure the mapping of interfaces to entity classes.

In your entity class, define the interface as target entity. Note that you have to use the full class name of the interface:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Foo\BarBundle\Entity\FoobarInterface")
 */
private $foobar;
```

In your `app/config/config.yml` add the following section:

```
doctrine :
    orm :
        resolve_target_entities :
            Foo\BarBundle\Entity\FoobarInterface : Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Foobar
```

Of course, you’re free to provide an `AbstractFoobar` class which implements some or all of the methods provided by `FoobarInterface`, but that’s irrelevant for Doctrine.

By the way, you don’t usually need the `@ORM\JoinTable` annotation. I don’t know where people keep getting that from, but it’s usually not needed and causes only trouble in many cases. Doctrine will handle the mapping implicitly. You only need that annotation if you explicitly want something different than what Doctrine would do by default.

Comment: So, can `resolve_target_entities` resolve to multiple discrete entities (I'm guessing yes, given the name, but would like confirmation/an example)?  Because, currently, my `AbstractProduct` has two concrete children: `Product` and `FabricProduct`.  Also, `@ORM\JoinTable` is in the Doctrine docs, specifically for a unidirectional many-to-many relationship, which is what I want (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional)

Comment: Every interface must resolve to exactly one interface. But one entity can implement multiple interfaces. You cannot have two entities implementing the same interface. If you have two similar entities, you should look into the [different inheritance patterns](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).

Comment: Ah, so `resolve_target_entities` only uses interfaces and not abstract classes?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.